# SHOW tables returns empty set, but MYI.Crypt files are there

Tags: mysql

Something really weird happened to my VPS last week. Suddenly, MySQL stopped working. My VPS has CentOS 6 and uses Parallels Plesk. After this, Parallels Plesk stopped working, and trying to start MySQL via SSH just gave me an error 
`Mysql daemon failed to start`.

I added this `skip-grant-tables` to my.cnf and I was able to start MySQL and access it... in MySQL I can see the database names. I selected the database using `use [database-name]` and I can select it, but when I use `show tables` it shows an empty set.

At this point I thought all the info is gone and that's it. But, outside MySQL, when I go to `/var/lib/mysql`, I see folders with the database names, and inside those folders, files with the table names `MYD.crypt` or `MYI.Crypt`.

At this point, all I want is to be able to create a dump file of a certain database. Is there a way to make MySQL use these files so I can recover that data and be able to export it?

Thank you.

Comment: MYD and MYI are for MyISAM tables.  Did you "encrypt" the database?

Answer (score 0):

There is more information need to troubleshooting.

1. What is the error logs for `Mysql daemon failed to start` for normal
   start?

   `[ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.`
2. What is the engine for MYD/MYI?
3. Do you have previous backups or replication site?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64633/discussion-on-answer-by-su-jun-ming-show-tables-returns-empty-set-but-myi-crypt).